# Scala presentation compiler locateTree method

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-macros

I've been using scala presentation compiler API, or to be more exact it's `locateTree` method to get AST of some piece of source code, and then get its raw representation via `showRaw(ast)` call, but the result seems to be different compared to what I expected. For instance

```
val tree = q"final def x = 1"
println(showRaw(tree))
```

Outputs `DefDef(Modifiers(FINAL), TermName("x"), List(), List(), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(1)))`, while a call to presentation compiler on the same source produces `DefDef(Modifiers(32, , List()), x, List(), List(), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(1)))` (notice that x is not wrapped in `TermName` and difference in `Modifiers` parameter list). Why does this happen and how can I enforce similar behaviour on presentation compiler?

**Edit:** scala version is 2.11.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trees are typed differently, so you have to use the correct `show`:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.tools.nsc._
import scala.tools.nsc._

scala> val ss = new Settings(println)
ss: scala.tools.nsc.Settings =
Settings {
  -d = .
}

scala> val g = new interactive.Global(ss, new reporters.ConsoleReporter(ss), "testing")
g: scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global = scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global@4c6007fb

scala> val tt = g.newUnitParser("final def x = 1").parseStats
tt: List[g.syntaxAnalyzer.global.Tree] = List(final def x = 1)

scala> reflect.runtime.universe.show(tt.head)
res0: String = final def x = 1

scala> reflect.runtime.universe.showRaw(tt.head)
res1: String = DefDef(Modifiers(32, , List()), x, List(), List(), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(1)))

scala> g.showRaw(tt)
res2: String = List(DefDef(Modifiers(FINAL), TermName("x"), List(), List(), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(1))))
```

There is no type safety at `res1`, so you don't realize the tree is from a different universe.

The trees are slightly different in modifiers because of position annotations:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.tools.nsc._
import scala.tools.nsc._

scala> val ss = new Settings(println)
ss: scala.tools.nsc.Settings =
Settings {
  -d = .
}

scala> new interactive.Global(ss, new reporters.ConsoleReporter(ss), "testing")
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global = scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global@4c6007fb

scala> val cc = res0
cc: scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global = scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global@4c6007fb

scala> val tt = cc.newUnitParser("final def x = 1").parseStats
tt: List[cc.syntaxAnalyzer.global.Tree] = List(final def x = 1)

scala> val cc.DefDef(mods, nam, ps, vs, tpt, rhs) = tt.head
mods: cc.Modifiers = Modifiers(final, , Map(32 -> RangePosition(<console>, 0, 0, 4), 72 -> RangePosition(<console>, 6, 6, 8)))
nam: cc.TermName = x
ps: List[cc.TypeDef] = List()
vs: List[List[cc.ValDef]] = List()
tpt: cc.Tree = <type ?>
rhs: cc.Tree = 1
```

as opposed to:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._, universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> val DefDef(mods, nam, ps, vs, tpt, rhs) = q"final def x = 1"
mods: reflect.runtime.universe.Modifiers = Modifiers(final, , Map())
nam: reflect.runtime.universe.TermName = x
ps: List[reflect.runtime.universe.TypeDef] = List()
vs: List[List[reflect.runtime.universe.ValDef]] = List()
tpt: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = <type ?>
rhs: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = 1
```

It turns out that `annotations` shows only explicit ones:

```
scala> mods.annotations
res13: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Tree] = List()
```

Worth mentioning that [the doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.Printers) says that `showRaw` is for inspection rather than construction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!